# Unable to publish libraries on Nexus Repository Manager 2.10

Tags: npm, nexus

To publish libraries at nexus npm private registry, package.json file is updated as below.

```
    "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "http://(IP):(port)/nexus/content/repositories/npm-private/"
  }
```

while publishing library with 'npm publish' command getting below error.

> npm ERR! code E401 npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: BASIC
>   realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository

Manager"

Nexus Repository Manager version 2.10 don't have realm setting available under security. Let us know if any additional configuration required for this or not. or  it is not supported in nexus Repository Manager 2.10.

Comment: I have resolved this issue by updating nexus repository manager version (may be 2.14)

Answer (score 0):

In NXRM2, your .npmrc has to have encoded credentials for your username/password.
See [here](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM2/Node+Packaged+Modules+and+npm+Registries#NodePackagedModulesandnpmRegistries-PublishingnpmPackages) (past the "publishConfig" section which you describe).